# Can't show loader in SSR page

Tags: reactjs, server-side-rendering

I have an SSR website written in React.
I'm using React Helmet to render meta data.
After adding a loader widget to the page I've noticed that the pages stopped rendering in the server and the Helment attributes returned empty.
I removed the loaded and my page [dinf](https://dinf.net/items/32528/GAN) looks cluttered now until loaded.
What is the preferred way to still show the loader in the browser?